# How to determine Node --max_old_space_size for a given memory limit?

Tags: node.js, v8

We run Node processes inside Docker containers with hard memory caps of 1GB, 2GB, or 4GB.  Each container generally just runs a single Node process (plus maybe a tiny shell script wrapper).  Let's assume for the purposes of this question that the Node process never forks more processes.

For our larger containers, if we don't set --max_old_space_size ourselves, then in the version of Node we use (on a 64-bit machine) it [defaults to 1400MB](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4.5-lkgr/src/api.cc#L493).  (This will [change to 2048MB](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/ec90ccb5ab4f464980898965474742962608a8a7) in a later version of Node.)

Ideally we want our Node process to use as much of the container as possible without going over and running out of memory.  The question is — what number should we use?  My understanding is that this particular flag tunes the size of one of the largest pools of memory used by Node, but it's not the only pool — eg, there's a "non-old" part of the heap, there's stack, etc.  How much should I subtract from the container's size when setting this flag in order to stay away from the cgroup memory limit but still make maximal use of the amount of memory allowed in this container?

I do note that from the same place where kMaxOldSpaceSizeHugeMemoryDevice is defined, it looks like the default "max semi space" is 16MB and the default "max executable size" is 512MB.  So I suspect this means I should subtract at least 528 from the container's memory limit when determining the value for this flag. But surely there are other ways that Node uses memory?

(To be more specific, we are a hosting service that sells containers of particular sizes to our users, most of which use them for Node processes. We'd like to be able to advise our customers as to what flag to set so that they neither are killed by our limits nor pay us for capacity that Node's configuration doesn't let them actually use.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, unfortunately, no particularly satisfactory answer to this question.

The constants you've found control the size of the garbage-collected heap, but as you've already guessed, there are many ways to consume memory that's not part of that heap:

- For example, big strings and big TypedArrays are typically managed by the embedder (i.e. node and its modules, not V8 itself), and outside the GC'ed heap.
- Node modules, in general, can consume whatever memory they want. Presumably you don't want to restrict what modules your customers can run, but that implies that you also can't predict how much memory those modules are going to require.
- V8 also uses temporary memory outside the GC'ed heap for parsing and compilation. Numbers depend on the code that's being run, from a few kilobytes up to a gigabyte or more (e.g. for huge asm.js codebases) anything is possible. These are relatively short-lived memory consumption peaks, so on the one hand you probably don't want to limit long-lived heap memory to account for them, but on the other hand that means they can make your processes run into the system limit.

Comment: When you say "Node modules", do you mean linked-in C++ code, or something else?

Comment: I mean native modules. Any C++ (and other non-JavaScript) code that runs can allocate memory outside of V8's control.